# Selenium download images without scrolling

Tags: python, selenium

I want to download more than 100 images from Google Images and avoid scrolling. I have searched several options but for my code I am getting a TimeOutException and I do not know why. 
I load a result page and then I am searching for the button "load more" (with CSS ID = smb) and try to click on it.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=table&tbm=isch&source=lnt&tbs=sur:fc&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVgKaq097gAhW7TBUIHd47DvkQpwUIIA&biw=1280&bih=933&dpr=1"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
page=driver.get(url)
try:
    mySelectElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "smb")))
    print(len(driver.page_source))
    mySelectElement.click()
except TimeoutException as ex:
    isrunning = 0
    print("Exception has been thrown. " + str(ex))
    driver.close()
    pass
```

Would be great to get any feedback!

Thanks!

Comment: Use `driver.save_screenshot('screenie.png')` to take a screenshot of the loaded image right after the `page = driver.get(url)` line

Comment: The page is dynamically generated, meaning that until you scroll down, you will not get the button. You can see this by doing a google image search, NOT scrolling and looking for the "Show more results" button with a Ctrl+F (Command+F on the Mac) and see that you will not find it.

Comment: There is no _load more_ button on the age as such, elements are populated through _lazy loading_

Comment: Thanks!

How can I then extend the web page via lazy loading so that an extended page is shown? In order to show more than 100 links ..

Comment: ok, found it ..via "driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 1000000)")"